# I am facing problem in Pseudocode overleaf error Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 615--615 ,Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup

Tags: pseudocode

this error I am getting
Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
Argument of \Return has an extra }.
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 615--615
Runaway argument?

```
\noindent\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Function{get\_network\_traffic}{}
  \State \Comment{Gets the current network traffic}
  \State $interfaces \gets$ \Call{get\_network\_io\_counters}{per\_interface = true}
  \State $network\_traffic \gets 0$
  \ForAll{$interface$ in $interfaces$}
    \State $network\_traffic \gets network\_traffic + interface.bytes\_recv + interface.bytes\_sent$
  \EndFor
  \State \Return $network\_traffic$
\EndFunction
\State
\State $network\_traffic \gets$ \Call{get\_network\_traffic}{}
\State \Print{"The current network traffic is " + $network\_traffic$ + " bytes."}
\end{algorithmic}
\end{minipage}% 
}
```

Comment: Welcome. // Unfortunately nobody can compile your code. Please try yourself and add what's missing (and needed to show your problem). Thank you

Comment: your error `argument of \Return has an extra `  means \Return takes an argument so  `\Return $` is `\Return {$}` and be a mis-matched `$` and will generate more errors.  It should probably be `\Return{$\mathit{network\_traffic}$}`  with an argument, but as we can not run the example as posted, this is untested.